# Запись экрана на android и ios | Unity

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-android

Хочу сделать так, чтобы в приложении можно было записывать видео при нажатии кнопки, как в инстаграме. Однако я не нашел рабочего способа реализовать это.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сдается, что вы не пробовали искать уже готовый функционал на эту тему

1. [Unity Recorder](https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/working-with-the-unity-recorder-2019-3#) - официальный пакет от юнити для записи видео демо геймплея в процессе игры. Одно но: работает только в редакторе, шикарный тутор по настройке и использованию по ссылке.
2. [Cross Platform Replay Kit : Record Every Play!](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/integration/cross-platform-replay-kit-record-every-play-133662) запись видео с экрана, но платный
3. [NatRecorder](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/integration/natcorder-video-recording-api-102645) - тоже запись, тоже платный. Есть [статья](https://medium.com/natsuite/natcorder-unity-recording-made-easy-f0fdee0b5055), описывающая возможности.
4. [Android_Screen_Recorder_Plugin](https://github.com/thanh-nguyen-kim/Android_Screen_Recorder_Plugin) - плагин с открытым кодом на github. Также у автора есть [репозиторий](https://github.com/thanh-nguyen-kim/Unity_Android_Screen_Recorder) с демонстрацией использования этого плагина. Бонусом [видео-туториал](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j3zGzbe9V1o&ab_channel=JoystickLab).

Все перечисленные варианты только на английском, но в большинстве можно разобраться исключительно по картинкам и видео.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Да, сейчас интегрировал для Android плагин Android_Utils_Plugin и для Ios использовал готовый функционал ReplayKit. Однако у меня возникла ещё одна проблема: мне нужно записывать видео, отделив слой интерфейса. Вы не знаете как это можно сделать? Т.е. чтобы в приложении кнопка записи видео была видна, а на самом видео - нет.

Comment: @BogdanBobkov точно не помню какой, но один из этих плагинов точно так умеет.  а учитывая, что в вашем варианте, вы дергаете нативный код платформ - мало вероятно, что выйдет отделить интерфейс. Чтобы такое было реально, вам нужно записывать видео на уровне самой юнити, а не натива. Если вам помог мой ответ, пометьте его, пожалуйста как верный и закроем вопрос. Или по крайней мере поставьте плюс ответу